# Quality diagnostics tool for database model

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I´m looking for one tool capable to analyse an existing db model (an Oracle schema in my setup) building a report with quality metrics, potential causes of problems (circular constraints, for example), etc.

We have this kind of features for Java code using tools like PMD or checkstyle.

Does anyone know about some tool like this for database structures?

Comment: What is a circular constraint, and why is it a problem? What other kinds of problems are you referring to? Also, I'm not aware of any "quality metrics" for a data model. "How normalised" is a possibility, but I don't know if this can even be determined mechanistically given just a schema design; let alone whether it would even be of any use.

Comment: A circular constraint (relationships between tables form a cycle) could be a problem if the final target row is the same as the original row. If I have a mechanism to identify circular constraints I will be able to check every one to be sure that doesn't happen. Other things to check could be existence of indexes or primary keys with business meaning, adherence to notation conventions.

Answer (score 1):

in quest software's TOAD there's a tool called code expert that does a lot of checks on stored code eg. views, stored procedures etc. maybee that can help